# C# Entity Framework one-to-many relationships, custom key

Tags: c#, one-to-many

I had a good automatic one-to-many relationship defined in an EF database code, based on a simple foreign key.

```
public class MyCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyItems Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyItems : List<MyItem> { }

public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MyCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string ItemsContents { get; set; }
}
```

This way, whenever I added a new `MyCategory` to the database and used `SaveChanges()`, it would automatically add the related list of all `MyItem`(s) to the respective MyItems database table.
Now, my leaders created a new requirement that the foreign key be a different non-auto-indexing `int` property, other than `Id`, in case tables are rebuilt and indexing IDs are lost. So we came up with the following:

```
public class MyCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MyCategoryId { get; set; }

    public MyItems Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyItems : List<MyItem> { }

public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MyCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string ItemsContents { get; set; }
}
```

The new idea is to use the same-named key in the 'one' table as is used in the 'many' table. Presumably, the `MyCategoryId` would be supplied to the `MyCategory` object as it's set into the database, and all the `MyItem`(s) would get automatically added just as before, but their `MyCategoryId` would be the same as the `MyCategory` one.

The problem is, the `MyCategoryId` of `MyItem` is still pulling from `Id` of `MyCategory`. I tried to experiment with putting the `[ForeignKey]` attribute everywhere, and using `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` to explicitly map `MyCategory.MyCategoryId` to `MyItem.MyCategoryId`, but have not achieved success and need help here on stackoverflow from anyone who may know. Thank you!

Here is a function I am trying to use to actually add the record.

```
 private void AddMyCategory(MyCategory myCat)
 {
   int prevId = 0;
   var prevFoundMyCategory = _context.MyCategories.OrderByDescending(m => m.MyCategoryId).Take(1);
   if(prevFoundMyCategory.FirstOrDefault() != null)
   {
     prevId = prevFoundMyCategory.First().MyCategoryId;
   }
   int nextId = prevId + 1;
   myCat.MyCategoryId = nextId;
   _context.MyCategories.Add(myCat);
   _context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

You could say, I'm trying to avoid this line, if it's possible to have EF do this automatically:

```
   foreach(var x in myCat.Items)
   {
     x.MyCategoryId = nextId;
   }
```

Actually, nope, even setting these like that does not work because EF overwrites whatever I set, with the `Id` property of the `MyCategory`...

Comment: So, why are you deriving the class `MyItems` from a List of `MyItem`?

Comment: I probably saw this way in some tutorial way back when.

Comment: Okay, when you say *The problem is, the MyCategoryId of MyItem is still pulling from Id of MyCategory*, are you submitting a form, or what are you doing?

Comment: Okay, I just tried it with changing it all to List<MyItem> but it still is the same issue. Yes, the form is submitting, I'm adding a new MyCategory to _context.MyCategories, then using _context.SaveChanges().
This puts the MyCategory.Id into MyItem.MyCategoryId, instead of putting in MyCategory.MyCategoryId

Comment: Can you post your form & controller?

Comment: There's a ton of code, but I'm going to put the function used to add the record.

Comment: Okay, so luckily I solved it, by putting the [Key] attribute in the custom ID field!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the ForeignKey and virtual collection got me half-way there, but I was missing the [Key] attribute being in the correct spot! In the end it should look more like:

```
public class MyCategory
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int MyCategoryId { get; set; }

    public List<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
}


public class MyItem
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MyCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string ItemsContents { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MyCategoryId")]
    public virtual MyCategory MyCategory { get; set; }
}
```